# Suggestions for why this html object would work on my computer, but not on my web host?

Tags: html

Seems simple enough, but I'm completely stuck. The following code works on my computer, but not on my host(siteground):

```
<html>
<body>
<object type="audio/mpeg" data="01.mp3"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

The mp3 lives in same folder. I've tried using its entire address (www.myurl.com/01.mp3), and moving it to a different directory. I also thought the problem could be with permissions- I've tried changing those but the issue persists.

I feel as though I am missing something simple or obvious.  Is it the way siteground is configured? I'm just looking for leads here.

EDIT:

On my mac, the page loads as just a quicktime symbol with a question mark over it.

EDIT 2:

In case anyone stumbles across this looking for guidance, this appears to be an issue with Safari 5 on snow leopard only: see the discussion [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2454051).

The only fix I can find is to actually re-encode the mp3 using LAME!

It also appears to not persist across every web host, but I can verify both siteground and godaddy.

So anyway, this really isn't a programming issue, but a bug in safari. The weird thing is that it works if you load the page locally- the issue has to be with the way something in that server works with safari 5's MIME types.

Comment: Could it be that your host does not allow serving mp3's?

Comment: does it take time to download the mp3?

Comment: Can you access the file directly by typing www.myurl.com/01.mp3 in the address bar?

Comment: If you can access the MP3 file as JMC indicates then check the Content-type header, siteground might not be setting it correctly.

Comment: @JMC creative, yes I can. @mu, this seems promising, I'll investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Your safest bet would be to put down the full path to the file. If you want to link to it the way you are, try "/01.mp3"

Comment: Unfortunately, neither '/01.mp3' nor 'www.myurl.com/01.mp3' work. I'm starting to wonder if this a thing with siteground, I just can't figure out exactly what

Comment: Try, emailing them then. Paid web-hosting should be friendly with this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the mp3 file you uploaded? e.g. change that to

```
<a href="01.mp3">link</a>
```

and work from there.

Comment: Does work, but the problem is I am trying to build a javascript-based mp3 player for a musician, and as I've built it now it relies on embedded audio object, a link to an mp3 doesn't work. I guess I could link to a 1px X 1px hidden iframe, but that will take some serious rewriting. Thanks!